# Receiving error when converting text to date in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am running a query that Redshift is throwing an error on "SQL Error [500310][57014]:Amazon Invalid operation: Error converting text to date;"

However, when I remove the Joined tables, or remove the conversions from the WHERE clause, it no longer throws an error. Thus I suspect something else is going on and this error is misleading.

I have looked at the data and it none of the dates look strange or out of range.

Here is the query that throws an error:

```
SELECT   m.member_id,
     t.tracker_id,
     DATE(ma.yyyymmdd) AS tracked_date,
     DATE(ma.updated_date) AS updated_date
FROM import_genesis.member_activities ma
INNER JOIN master."member" m
    ON ma.memberid = m.member_legacy_id
INNER JOIN master.action_activity aa
    ON ma.activity_type = aa.activity_type
INNER JOIN master.tracker t
    ON t.action_id = aa.action_id
WHERE DATE(ma.yyyymmdd) > DATE(DATEADD(DAY, -14, GETDATE()))
AND DATE(ma.yyyymmdd) <= GETDATE();
```

Here are two queries that do NOT throw an error:

```
SELECT  DATE(ma.yyyymmdd) AS tracked_date,
        DATE(ma.updated_date) AS updated_date
FROM import_genesis.member_activities ma
WHERE DATE(ma.yyyymmdd) > DATE(DATEADD(DAY, -14, GETDATE()))
AND DATE(ma.yyyymmdd) <= GETDATE();
```

```
SELECT  m.member_id,
        t.tracker_id,
        DATE(ma.yyyymmdd) AS tracked_date,
        DATE(ma.updated_date) AS updated_date
FROM import_genesis.member_activities ma
INNER JOIN master."member" m
    ON ma.memberid = m.member_legacy_id
INNER JOIN master.action_activity aa
    ON ma.activity_type = aa.activity_type
INNER JOIN master.tracker t
    ON t.action_id = aa.action_id;
```

Any ideas as to what might be wrong or any potential workarounds?

Comment: Note that GETDATE() function actually returns timestamp datatype, not date. I guess you should use current_date function instead.
I would also suggest to use implicit masks when converting text to data/timestamp.
Try to use TO_DATE(ma.yyyymmdd,'YYYYMMDD') (or whatever correct mask is in this case) instead of DATE(ma.yyyymmdd).

There is always potential problems if two different datatypes are compared. When executing query database decides itself to which datatype it will convert before comparison. Small changes in SQL can affect this behavior.

Comment: Thanks for this response. I thought TO_DATE was only for varchar conversion to date. However, trying this led me to find the answer: one of the entries in the date column indeed had an invalid date. 

Not to go off topic, but how would I identify exactly which entry is causing the problem when I get a query error like this?

Comment: As you didn't descibed columns, I assumed that ma.yyyymmdd is text/varchar.
Checking if date is valid is a bit more complicated. I would start to check if specific substrings are in range between expected values. For example: left('20190101',4) between '1900' and '2100'